# Is NUnit TestContext.CurrentContext safe to use in parallel tests?

Tags: c#, multithreading, nunit

## Background

An NUnit framework extension that I'm working on needs to know the outcome/result of each test from within an `ITestAction` attribute, like so:

```
public class MyFrameworkExtensionAttribute : Attribute, ITestAction
{
  public void BeforeTest(ITest test)
  { /* Omitted, not relevant to this question */ }

  public void AfterTest(ITest test)
  {
    var result = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result;
    var resultIsSuccess = result.Outcome.Status == TestStatus.Passed;
    // Then go on to do stuff with that resultIsSuccess variable
  }
}
```

Note the first line in the `AfterTest` method; I'm using a static reference: **TestContext.CurrentContext**. The `ITest` interface doesn't expose the result of the test, so it seems test context is the only way.

## Question

And now my question - because NUnit 3.x includes functionality to run tests in parallel, via `ParallelizableAttribute` - I'm wondering: Is it safe to use that static reference to the current test context?  Are there any thread-safety concerns I should be worried about here?  Is there a better/more robust way to get the test outcome without resorting to a static reference?

I'm using NUnit framework 3.7.1 in case it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Mid-size answer: Although it's a static property, we only use it for easy access to the actual context, which is unique for each test.

Explanation: 
Each use of `TestContext.CurrentContext` creates a new context, which is not an expensive operation because it's merely a wrapper for `TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext`. The current execution context is maintained in different ways depending on the platform build of the nunit framework. For desktop .NET we use the `CallContext` to store it.